# Android assets allocation error

Tags: android, memory, instance, memory-leaks, assets

I need to create a new Typeface every time a change occurres in app (a Live Wallpaper) font preferences.

To do this, I create a Typeface in onSharedPreferenceChanged() in my wallpaper Engine, this way:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

         typeface = prefs.getString("customize_font_settings", "MyFont.ttf");
         AssetManager assmManager = App.getContext().getAssets();
         font = Typeface.createFromAsset(assmManager, typeface);
```

Where **App.getContext().getAssets()** refers to a static instance, in order to get correctly the AssetManager.

The fact is that every time **onSharedPreferenceChanged()** a new instance of AssetManager is created, making it overflow easily the memory.

How can I create a SINGLE instance of AssetManager which will remain still and will not clone itself?

Answer (score 0):

In App, why not make a static function that returns a static reference to asset manager? You are already half way there.

App

```
public static AssetManager getManager(){
   if(this.assetManager == null) AssetManager this.assetManager = this.getAssets();

   return this.assetManager;

}
```

Shared

```
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(App.getManager(), typeface);
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited the App class this way to make sgarman code work, but this doesn't solve the issue:

First of all, I can't use "this." in a static context, so I had to re-write the **getManager()** class this way:

```
    private static AssetManager assetManager;


    public static AssetManager getManager(){

        if(assetManager == null) assetManager = mContext.getAssets();

           return assetManager;

        }
```

This doesn't solve the issue. Still assets duplicating.